# How do I set a boolean inside a for loop to true if a value is reached?

Tags: java

I want to set the boolean additionalLogging value to true inside a for loop if 2 has been reached. How can I set it to a "global" or "public" value outside of the brackets?

I just want it to be true for the next value 8.

Any ideas?

```
public class userAnalytic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean additionalLogging = false;
        System.out.println(additionalLogging);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            if (i == 5) {
                if (additionalLogging == true) {
                    System.out.println("We found 5");
                    if (i == 2) {
                        additionalLogging = true;
                        if (i == 8) {
                            if (additionalLogging = true) {
                                System.out.println("8 has been found");
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Solved. Solution:

```
public class userAnalytic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean additionalLogging = false;
        System.out.println(additionalLogging);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            if (i == 5) {
                if (additionalLogging == true) {
                    System.out.println("We found 5");
                }
            }
            if (i == 7) {
                additionalLogging = true;
                System.out.println("okay");
            }

            if (i == 8) {
                if (additionalLogging = true) {
                    System.out.println("8 has been found");
                }

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `additionalLogging = true` do you mean `==`?

Comment: I think you have bigger problems with that code. See, at each iteration you check the value of "i". Then if it's 5 you enter the if. Within that if, you check if "i" is 2 and then within you check if it's 8. Now: at any given moment i can either be 5, 2 or 8 but not all 3... so you'll never reach the contents of if i==2 and therefore neither you will reach the contents of if i==8

Comment: @AndyTurner worth saying that you've meant the most inner if condition.

Comment: The only code in your loop that sets `additionalLogging` to `true` is in an `if` block that is only entered if `additionalLogging` is **already** `true`. So this is a logic issue, not a syntax issue; you'll never set it `true`. (But separately, the inner `if (additionalLogging = true)` should be using `==`, not `=`.) (Also separately: Don't use `if (x == true)` and `if (x== false)`, use `if (x)` and `if (!x)` [with **rare** exceptions].)

Comment: just use `if (additionalLogging) {`

Comment: I strongly recommend using the debugger built into your IDE to step through your code statement by statement. Using the debugger isn't something you need to wait to  do until you're no longer a beginner, it's a **crucial** skill for every beginner to learn. It's basically the first thing you should learn after writing "Hello, Java" (if not *while* writing it).

Comment: AS T.J.Crowder said, I would also strongly recommend, using a debugger and more important a State of the art IDE. This would have shown you, what you are doing wrong, e.g. the assignment instead of the == check.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help!

Thank you @T.J.Crowder, I will start to use it.

The solution was the misplaced brackets. I didn't really close the if statement properly like how I should have done it.

Comment: You should accept an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop nesting all of your `if` conditions. The way it's written, each inner `if` depends on the outer one to be true, but `i` can obviously not be `5`, `2` and `8` all at the same time.

Also, when testing a boolean value for truth you don't need to use `== true`, it's superfluous. And if you have two conditions that you're checking at the same time, you can just combine them with the `&&` operator, instead of nesting them.

If I understand your intent correctly, you probably meant to do something like this:

```
public class userAnalytic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean additionalLogging = false;
        System.out.println(additionalLogging);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            if (i == 5 && additionalLogging) {
                System.out.println("We found 5");
            }
            if (i == 2) {
                additionalLogging = true;
            }
            if (i == 8 && additionalLogging) {
                System.out.println("8 has been found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now each of these conditions will be evaluated *separately* during each loop iteration; when`i` is `2` the `additionalLogging` flag will be set to `true`, and then when `i` hits `5` and `8` your log statements will get displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Your first if is (i == 5) and everything is inside this statement.
Probably, you want to do this:

```
public class userAnalytic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       boolean additionalLogging = false;
       System.out.println(additionalLogging);
       for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
           System.out.println(i);
           if (i == 5) {
               if (additionalLogging == true) {
                   System.out.println("We found 5");
               }
           }
           if (i == 2) {
               additionalLogging = true;
           }
           if (i == 8) {
               if (additionalLogging = true) {
                   System.out.println("8 has been found");
               }
           }
       }
   }
```